# give remote driver capability to download a file to specified location

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to download a file with selenium/python and later read from that file.

When I use non remote driver as below, it downloads file and all is gucci

```
def initialize():
     global instance
     chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
     prefs = {'download.default_directory':'/Users/dusandev/Desktop/StreamFlowWebTests/reporting/wallets'}
     chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
     instance = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
     instance.implicitly_wait(2)
     return instance
```

However, when I use remote driver, it fails with and does not download the file.

```
def initialize():
     global instance
     chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
     prefs = {'download.default_directory':'/Users/dusandev/Desktop/StreamFlowWebTests/reporting/wallets'}
     chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
     instance = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities.CHROME, options=chrome_options)
     instance.implicitly_wait(2)
     return instance
```

The error is following:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/dusandev/Desktop/StreamFlowWebTests/reporting/wallets/solflare-backup.txt'
```

I also tried to make folder writable with adding rw to the end of the folder like this

```
{'download.default_directory':'/Users/dusandev/Desktop/StreamFlowWebTests/reporting/wallets:rw'}
```

That did not work as well.

Do you have any idea? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download directory you're specifying needs to be a directory on the remote server.  Selenium doesn't provide a way to fetch downloads through a remote.  If you have access, you can `scp` it from the server.

[How to download a file using the remote selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068912/how-to-download-a-file-using-the-remote-selenium-webdriver)